# Is there a way to programmatically backup and restore Azure database with a bacpac or similar?

Tags: azure, backup, bacpac

So I am migrating a database from a local SQL Server 2014 to an Azure database.  I migrated successfully using a bacpac and the connections are working fine.  However I still want to perform backups and of course the old school file backup does not work.  So I hunted around and saw that Microsoft recommends backing up to blob storage.  At a cost of course along with other things.

My question is, is there an easy way to use SMO references or similar to just remotely make a bacpac stored locally and then used remotely as needed?  My real issue is maintainability and if I ever wanted to switch back to local to not be so iron clad bound to azure methods.  I feel a bacpac may do this.

So far I of course tried using file backups, which of course the syntax won't even work.  I then started looking at this link: https://jasonstrate.com/2013/04/18/backing-up-azure-sql-database-to-the-cloud/ and was working on it.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Azure SQL it offers built-in backups up up 90 (not sure, 35 for sure) days without you having to do anything. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups).

Comment: That is interesting but two things I noticed in just doing it.  It creates a new database from the restore and does not overwrite the existing out of the box.  I still would need a method with either Azure Powershell, API, or other calls to do this.  That is awesome though they included that out of the box now as part of Azure built in.